# Pandas function gather tidyverse-like

Tags: python, r, pandas, tidyverse

I got a long df like this:

```
State | Population 1998 | Population 1999| Population 2000 | ... | Population 2018
A     | 4534534         | 41534534       | 234234434       | ... | 21312323   
B     | 23433242        | 34323423       | 456456546       | ... | 54645655  
C     | 4534534         | 41534534       | 234234434       | ... | 21312323   
D     | 4534534         | 41534534       | 234234434       | ... | 21312323   
E     | 4534534         | 41534534       | 234234434       | ... | 21312323   
F     | 7897998         | 87878788       | 912391233       | ... | 1012391233
```

I would have a new df like:

```
State     | Year | Population 
A         | 1998 | 4534534    
A         | 1999 | 41534534       
A         | 2000 | 234234434       
.....        
F         | 2018 | 1012391233
```

I can make this on R with tidyverse function gather.. My question is.. How can i do this on pandas? :)
Thank you for your answers and your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert non population column to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then `split` columns to `MultiIndex`, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and convert `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index('State')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split(expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack().rename_axis(('State','Year')).reset_index()
print (df1.head(10))
  State  Year  Population
0     A  1998     4534534
1     A  1999    41534534
2     A  2000   234234434
3     A  2018    21312323
4     B  1998    23433242
5     B  1999    34323423
6     B  2000   456456546
7     B  2018    54645655
8     C  1998     4534534
9     C  1999    41534534
```

Or use `rename` with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df1 = (df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace('Population ', ''))
        .melt('State', var_name='Year', value_name='Population'))
print (df1.head(10))
  State  Year  Population
0     A  1998     4534534
1     B  1998    23433242
2     C  1998     4534534
3     D  1998     4534534
4     E  1998     4534534
5     F  1998     7897998
6     A  1999    41534534
7     B  1999    34323423
8     C  1999    41534534
9     D  1999    41534534
```

Thank you, @sammywemmy for suggestion use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                      stubnames='Population',
                      i='index',
                      j='Year', 
                      sep=' ').reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df1.head(10))
   Year State  Population
0  1998     A     4534534
1  1998     B    23433242
2  1998     C     4534534
3  1998     D     4534534
4  1998     E     4534534
5  1998     F     7897998
6  1999     A    41534534
7  1999     B    34323423
8  1999     C    41534534
9  1999     D    41534534
```

Comment: ```wide_to_long``` too ?

Answer (score 0):

`gather` is superseded by `pivot_longer`.

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) in python, you are able to do it with the same API design:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas 
from datar.all import f, starts_with, pivot_longer, NA

data = StringIO("""State|Population 1998|Population 1999|Population 2000|Population 2018
A     | 4534534         | 41534534       | 234234434       | 21312323   
B     | 23433242        | 34323423       | 456456546       | 54645655  
C     | 4534534         | 41534534       | 234234434       | 21312323   
D     | 4534534         | 41534534       | 234234434       | 21312323   
E     | 4534534         | 41534534       | 234234434       | 21312323   
F     | 7897998         | 87878788       | 912391233       | 1012391233""")


df = pandas.read_csv(data, sep="|")

df >> pivot_longer(
    starts_with('Population'), 
    names_to=[".value", "Year"], 
    names_sep=" "
)
```

```
    State   Year    Population
0   A   1998    4534534
1   A   1999    41534534
2   A   2000    234234434
3   A   2018    21312323
4   B   1998    23433242
5   B   1999    34323423
6   B   2000    456456546
7   B   2018    54645655
8   C   1998    4534534
9   C   1999    41534534
10  C   2000    234234434
11  C   2018    21312323
12  D   1998    4534534
13  D   1999    41534534
14  D   2000    234234434
15  D   2018    21312323
16  E   1998    4534534
17  E   1999    41534534
18  E   2000    234234434
19  E   2018    21312323
20  F   1998    7897998
21  F   1999    87878788
22  F   2000    912391233
23  F   2018    1012391233
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.